# Promise returning undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to use promise to send an ajax request to a php script which checks if a file exist on the server and returns a boolean value.

I have the below code but the fileExists function always return undefined.

How can I wrap the promise in a function and have the function return the promise value?

```
function fileExists(url) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }); 
    promise.then(function(e) {
        return e;
    });
}

var result = fileExists("url_to_file");
```

Comment: no, `fileExists` returns undefined, because you don't return anything from that function

Comment: change `var promise =` to `return` ... remove the `promise.then` null function, and finally, realise that `var result = fileExists("url_to_file");` will mean `result` is a **Promise** - if you want to wait for the promise to fulfill you'll need to do `result.then(function(result) { ... code to use result ...})`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q063hakm/

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X, this is exactly what was causing the undefined return in my fileExists function

Comment: Thanks Rayon for the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fileExists(url) {
  return promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  }); 
}

fileExists("url_to_file").then(text => console.log(text));
```

Your function returns nothing. If you return the promise you can hold on to the data once it's resolved.

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code:

```
promise.then(function(e) {
    return e;
});
```

only returns `e` to the **callback function**. You have to handle the result **within** that callback.

```
promise.then(function() {
    // handle result;
});
```

Or might as well return the promise as shown by @Ole.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the promise, because you need to assign your result variable asynchronous.

```
function fileExists(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

fileExists("url_to_file").then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function must return a `Promise`.

```
function fileExists(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Then just call the function and print the resolved text

```
fileExists("url_to_file").then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```