# Axios Returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
//agent.js
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api';
    
    const requests = {
      createUser: (payload) => {
        axios.post('/users/create', payload);
      },
      getUsers: () => {
        axios.get('/users').then((r) => {
          console.log(r.data); //outputs the json response
          return r.data;
        });
      }
    };
    
    const agent = {
      requests
    };
    
    export default agent;

//reactComponent.js

import agent from './agent';
function Userlist() {
  const users = agent.requests.getUsers();
  console.log(users); //outputs undefined
}
```

What am I doing wrong as I get an undefined when making the request from my reactComponent.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691804/promise-returning-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything in your `getUsers` function.

```
getUsers: () => {
    axios.get('/users').then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data); //outputs the json response
      return r.data;
    });
}
```

Remove the function bracket and it should work,

```
getUsers: () => 
    axios.get('/users').then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data); //outputs the json response
      return r.data;
    });
```

Comment: now its returns a promise. i thought the then function resolves that issue?

Comment: Not really, you will have to resolve the returned promise as well.

Comment: @user31529 Once you have a promise, you can never make it synchronous -- all code that depends on it has to be chained off it, either using `then` or `await`. The consequence of this is that `Userlist` has to be made asynchronous too with `await`, or use `then` inside of it and chain the code that depends on the users from it (probably ending in a `setState` call of some sort).